# Xcode Warning: "no rule to process file" and "Directory not found"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

After renaming my project folder I get the following error messages:

```
    Warning: no rule to process file '/Users/cs/Documents/Xcode/Prototype/Prototype/Settings.bundle' 
of type wrapper.plug-in for architecture i386

    Warning: no rule to process file '/Users/cs/Documents/Xcode/Prototype/Prototype/DDMathParser/DDMathParser.h' 
of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386

    Warning: no rule to process file '/Users/cs/Documents/Xcode/Prototype/Prototype/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h' 
of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386

Directory not found for option '-L"/Users/cs/Documents/Xcode/Prototype/Prototype/../../../FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework"
```

Any idea on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Concerning the 3 first warning, you may check in XCode in the "Build Phases" inside your project settings that the header files do not appear inside the "Compile Sources" list.

[image]